# How to run web projects on Mediam level trust on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am working on a MVC4 project, where i am using PDF report 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC
using iTextsharp and iTextsharp.worker. It works fine on the local machine.

But when i host the project on godaddy server every thing goes fine except the Pdf reports. it throws Security error showing the trust level issue. I google for some time and find out godaddy supports medium level trust. And when we develop project, visual studio by default it uses trust level Full.

i even tried to used
    
      
     
section on my web config file, when i am working on local machine. But even it self is throwing error.

So i want know if it would be possible to run my project on medium trust on my visual studio, as i do every day for development.

Comment: what did you try in the `web.config` ? `<trust level="Medium" />` ?

Comment: yes as i mentioned it, when i use it inside system.web, it throws Error saying - It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Build > Clean command in VS.

Also check the Machine.config file of the .NET framework you're using and make sure `allowOverride` is `true` - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wyts434y(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wyts434y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

As a last resort set `<trust level="Medium" />` in Machine.config.